# Minha String está dando erro "unicodeescape"

Tags: python

Estou tentando abrir um arquivo com dados `.txt` no Python mas aparece uma mensagem de erro.

```
arq = open('C:\Users\Cintia\Documents\Python\Dados\lbe.txt', 'r')
lbe = arq.read()
print(lbe)
arq.close()
```

O erro é `unicodeescape`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O caminho de um arquivo no Windows gera um conflito no Python devido à barra invertida. Quando você utiliza, por exemplo, `C:\Users`, o Python irá interpretar o caractere `\U` como um U escapado, semelhante ao o que ocorre com o `\n` para quebrar linha.

Para contornar esse erro, você precisa prefixar a *string* com um `r`, para indicar ao interpretador Python que a *string* deve ser analisada de forma "crua" (o `r` é de *raw string*), ficando assim:

```
arq = open(r'C:\Users\Cintia\Documents\Python\Dados\lbe.txt', 'r')
```

Comment: Esses dados que importei, é possível fazer o plot, porque aparece uma sequencia de erros. Desde já agradeço

Comment: Não entendi o que quis dizer. Que plot? Você precisa de algum tipo de gráfico? Talvez seja questão para outra pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

O problema é com a string `'C:\Users\Cintia\Documents\Python\Dados\lbe.txt'`.

**`\U`** começa um escape Unicode de 8 caracteres e, como é sucedido por `s`, que é uma sequência inválida, estoura o erro. O mesmo aconteceria com outras sequências, como **`\r`**, **`\n`**, **`\t`** e assim por diante. Por isso, sempre que for representar um *backslash*, é bom duplicá-lo, fazendo com que ele seja escapado também. Assim você sempre vai ter certeza de que o valor produzido será apenas uma **`\`**.

Isso pode ser resolvido usando dois *backslashes* para representar caminhos no Windows.

```
arq = open('C:\\Users\\Cintia\\Documents\\Python\\Dados\\lbe.txt', 'r')
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema talvez seja no \U de "C:\Users". Talvez, você deva falar que o caminho é uma rawstring. Tente algumas das opções abaixo:
Exemplo 1:

```
arq = open(r'C:\Users\Cintia\Documents\Python\Dados\lbe.txt', 'r')
```

Ou então:

```
arq = open'''C:\Users\Cintia\Documents\Python\Dados\lbe.txt''', 'r')
```