# Como listar arquivos em uma pasta com tamanho

Tags: python

Olá, preciso listar todos os arquivos em uma pasta com diversas subpastas, preciso do nome e do tamanho de todos os arquivos dessa pasta, estou tentando fazer um código em Python para isso mas não estou conseguindo, alguém pode ajudar por favor?

Comecei no trabalho essa semana e ainda estou aprendendo a usar python, logo não tenho o código pronto.

Comment: Poderia [edit] a pergunta adicionando o código que fez até agora e descrevendo qual foi o resultado obtido? Seria interessante também adicionar de exemplo uma estrutura de pasta e colocar qual seria o resultado esperado para esse exemplo.

Comment: Relacionada: [Listar arquivos de um pasta em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63097/listar-arquivos-de-um-pasta-em-python)

Comment: Jean, muito cuidado para não desvirtuar sua pergunta com as edições. Ao adicionar novas solicitações você inviabiliza as respostas atuais. Se a sua intenção era gerar uma planilha com os valores, isso deveria estar descrito desde o início. Você já viu como é listar os arquivos e os respectivos tamanhos, então acho que já tem material o suficiente para tentar gerar a planilha sozinho. Se não conseguir, abra uma nova pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

A partir da versão 3.4 do Python não tem motivos para utilizar o pacote `os`. Foi adicionado um novo pacote, [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), para lidar com diretórios e arquivos que abstrai muito de maneira mais organizada as funções para gerenciar um diretório.

Se considerarmos uma estrutura de pastas:

```
pasta/
    subpasta/
        subpasta/
            arquivo_4.txt
        arquivo_3.txt

    arquivo_1.txt
    arquivo_2.txt
```

Podemos fazer:

```
from pathlib import Path

pasta = Path('pasta')

for f in pasta.glob('**/*'):
    if f.is_file():
        print(f.name, f.stat().st_size)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/OnlyMediocreServers)</sup>

A saída seria semelhante à:

```
arquivo_2.txt 0
arquivo_1.txt 0
arquivo_3.txt 0
arquivo_4.txt 0
```

Comment: Deu esse error:

runfile('D:/Users/diogo.silva/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='D:/Users/diogo.silva/.spyder-py3')
  File "D:/Users/diogo.silva/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 3
    pasta = Path('D:\Users\diogo.silva\teste')
                ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: @JeanRibeiro Isso é outro erro não relacionado ao da pergunta: [Minha String está dando erro “unicodeescape”](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/250827/5878)

Comment: Valeeeeu, consegui, mas como são mais de 9k de arquivos, tem como eu jogar esses dados direto em uma planilha do excel atraves do python?

Comment: @JeanRibeiro Tem como, sim. Ao invés do `print` basta você gravar no arquivo os dados que deseja.

Comment: Valeu, muito obrigado, há alguma forma de imprimir essa lista em kbytes? quando estou imprimindo a lista vem em bytes

Comment: @JeanRibeiro Quantos bytes são 1kbyte?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode gerar um dicionário com todos os arquivos e tamanhos com o seguinte código:

```
import os

path = "C:\\seu\\path\\"
lista = [f for f in os.listdir(path)]
tamanhos = []
dict_arquivos = {}

for item in lista:
    dict_arquivos[item] = os.path.getsize(path+item)

print(dict_arquivos)
```

Comment: Qual versão do Python você está utilizando?

Comment: Tinha esquecido de colocar o os na frente. Arrumei o código, Wallace.

Comment: Deu esse error:

runfile('D:/Users/diogo.silva/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='D:/Users/diogo.silva/.spyder-py3')
  File "D:/Users/diogo.silva/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 3
    path = "D:\Users\diogo.silva\teste"
          ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Answer (score 0):

De maneira bem reduzida, você pode escrever o seu código assim:

```
from os import path, listdir

pasta = '/diretorio'

lista = [dict(arquivo=f, tamanho=path.getsize(path.join(pasta, f))) for f in listdir(pasta)]
```

O resultado será algo parecido com:

```
[
    {'arquivo': 'nota fiscal 08 04 2019.pdf', 'tamanho': 11074}, 
    {'arquivo': 'nota fiscal 08 05 2019.pdf', 'tamanho': 11069}, 
    {'arquivo': 'install.sh', 'tamanho': 1374}, 
    {'arquivo': 'NOTA FISCAL.pdf', 'tamanho': 11028}, 
    {'arquivo': 'test.pdf', 'tamanho': 176427}
]
```

No exemplo acima, usamos um [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) para gerar uma `list` com um `dict`, contendo os valores `arquivo  e`tamanho`.

A função `path.join` é usada com a variável `pasta` porque o `listdir` não retorna o caminho completo do arquivo, mas apenas o nome base dele dentro da pasta.

Nos testes que fiz, usei a versão 3.6 e 2.7 do Python.

## Recursão

Se precisar de listar tanto diretórios como subdiretórios, eu sugiro usar recursão. Eu fiz da seguinte forma:

```
from os import path, walk

pasta = '/home/wallace/Documentos'

def recursive_walk(pasta):

    lista = []

    for raiz, subdirs, arquivos in walk(pasta):
        for f in arquivos:
            arquivo = path.join(raiz, f)
            lista.append(dict(arquivo=arquivo, tamanho=path.getsize(arquivo)))

        for subdir in subdirs:
            lista += recursive_walk(subdir)


    return lista

lista = recursive_walk(pasta)

print(lista)
```

Comment: Olá, consegui rodar o programa, mas são mais de 9k de arquivos, tem alguma forma de eu jogar esses arquivos na planilha do excel?